# How to Redirect after Click on Button

Tags: redirect, io-redirection, post-redirect-get

I'm using Landing page so I already have button I want to redirect people after clicking on this button the button id is: button-c86b272c I want to redirect people after clicking on this button not create new button .

I have this code to redirect after time out :

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10; URL=www.google.com/" />`

but I want one to redirect after click on exicting button not new button I tried change the first code to this :

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" onclick="button-c86b272c; URL=www.google.com/" />`

but it did not work something isn't right
Hope You help me

Comment: Are you asking how to perform a redirect in JavaScript?  How to submit an HTML form?  How to style a link to look like a button?  How to attach a click handler to a button?  Something else?  Also, what do the `io-redirection` and `post-redirect-get` tags have to do with this?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The `meta` tag is not a visible DOM element, it means it does not have a "body", thus cannot be clicked on. `meta` tag is used to describe metadata about your page, or set HTTP headers.

To redirect to a specific URL after the button is clicked you can use JavaScript:

```js
// First we need to create a handle to the DOM element
const buttonElement = document.getElementById("button-c86b272c");
// Then we add an event listener, which will execute a passed function after the event (in our case "click") is fired
buttonElement.addEventListener("click", () => {
  // We set the destination URL, the page reloads automatically
  window.locaton = "www.google.com/";
});
```

Add this code to your page or put it in a separate file and make sure to import it or you can add the event listener directly in your HTML using the `onclick` property, like this:

```html
<button id="button-c86b272c" onclick="window.location = 'www.google.com/'"></button>
```

However this approach is not recommended and it's best to put your JavaScript in a separate file and not mix it into the HTML.

Hope this helps!